# Vizualizar arquivos PDF em VB6

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Tenho um diretório no servidor que é criado conforme o livro e folha, onde ao escanear imagens ele é salvo através do livro e folhas físicos.

*exemplo:* Tenho um livro que tenho três paginas, sendo que o numero do livro é 1022 e as folhas são 140, 141,142, isto é, serão escaneados 3 folhas do livro 1022 ficando assim no diretório:

```
\\servidor\imagens\L1022\L1022F140\L1022F140.pdf
\\servidor\imagens\L1022\L1022F140\L1022F141.pdf
\\servidor\imagens\L1022\L1022F140\L1022F142.pdf
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer  é  carregar em uma lista e vizualizar cada um deles através de um de dois botões <kbd>Avançar</kbd> e <kbd>Retroceder</kbd>

Tudo isso gostaria de fazer em VB6.

Meu código atual:

```
Private Sub cmdVisualiza_Click()

Dim ArqNumstrPathServer As String
Dim ArqNum As String
Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
Dim FSfolder As Folder
Dim subfolder As Folder
Dim I As Integer
Dim Path As String
Path = "\\Luciano\\Imagens\\gerdoc\\"
ArqNum = "L" & txtLivro & "F" & txtFolha
Botao = "L" & txtLivro & "F" & txtFolha

sFolderPath = Path & "L" & txtLivro & "\\" & Botao & "\\"
```

Comment: Consegui resolver.